# Increased Rount Trip Time using Scapy

Tags: sockets, ping, scapy, mininet

I have created a network topology such as H1 <-> S1 <-> S2 <-> H2 in Mininet. Where H are Hosts and S are Switches. The network has been created as follows [image]

I have set the delay in the network as 1ms. When I run Ping between H1 and H2, I get result such as follows, [image]

We can see that the RTT is approx. similar to topology.

If send a packet using Scapy from H1 to H2 using sendp(), the RTT is increasing. I am sending packet as follows[image]

If I use socket programming on the same network, then I get RTT = 2ms(approx.)
I want to know what is going wrong with Scapy.

Comment: Hi & welcome to stackoverflow. As a general rule, please always post *code* instead of *pictures* of the code. As much as I'd like to help, I'm not zooming in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is anything wrong here. You specified 1ms on your link, the RTT is when a packet comes and then comes back. So you have 1ms * 2 = 2ms. If you want to achieve 1ms RTT you have to specify a 0.5ms latency on the link.